# get the value of simplexmlelement object php

Tags: php, simplexml

I try too many thing to read the value of the [label] from the code below :

```
    Array ( [0] => 
    SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
       [id] => x 
       [published] => 2011
       [category] =>
     Array ( [0] => 
      SimpleXMLElement Object 
      ( 
      [@attributes] => 
        Array (
        [scheme] => y 
        [term] => t 
        ) )
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object 
        ( [@attributes] => 
        Array (
        [scheme] => y2 
        [term] => Film
        [label] => Film & Animation 
        ) )
```

it start with numeric array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP get values from SimpleXMLElement array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751711/php-get-values-from-simplexmlelement-array), see also the [Basic Usage Examples in the manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: tanx , i saw those , but it did not work for me , it has 2 dim array ... really condused :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your answer as simple as:

```
$data->category['label']?
```

See simplexml documentation next time, all attributes are accessible from an array, and all subnodes are accessible through the object property operator.

If you have many categories, then you will have an array at "category[0]"

Comment: Oh wait, i hadn't seen the structure correctly, it is in fact: $data->category[1]['label']