# How to obtain attributes from SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP get values from SimpleXMLElement array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751711/php-get-values-from-simplexmlelement-array)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [TotalAmount] => 4.75
        )
)
```

`$services_arr->attributes` returns null

`$services_arr->@attributes` returns an error

My question is: How to get toal amount `4.75` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return total amount in float:

```
$total_amount = (float)$services_arr['TotalAmount'];
```

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

This blank object return.

Comment: Just edited my solution for a better way of obtaining the result.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to create a function inside your class, that returns the desired value something like this:

```
public function getTotalAmount () {
  return $this -> total_amount;
}
```

And ask for it like this:

```
$services_arr -> getTotalAmount();
```

This will make the code safer too, it's not good practise, to ask directly for values.

Comment: Abouve XML return by api . how i use getTotalAmount function ?