# Access to SimpleXMLElement Object value

Tags: php, xml, object

I have the code below:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object(
    [@attributes] => Array(
        [id] => 542
        [url] => http://google.pl
        [price] => 19.29
        [avail] => 1
        [set] => 0
    )
)
```

How can I get access to id with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP get values from SimpleXMLElement array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751711/php-get-values-from-simplexmlelement-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$attributes = $simpleXmlElement->attributes();
echo $id = $attributes['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function xml_attribute($object, $attribute)
{
    if(isset($object[$attribute]))
        return (string) $object[$attribute];
}
print xml_attribute($xml, 'id'); //prints "542"
```

I can get the "id" like this